# Java execute shell command auto update view

Tags: java, jsp, command-line, streaming

I want to achieve the following but I can't find the proper way to tackle it. My `webapp`, at some point gives the user the ability to press a `button` and `execute` remotely a `command` (actually perform a `maven build`: `mvn clean package`). What I want, is to auto update a `jsp` page with the console output of the `mvn command`, sort of what Jenkins is doing when we perform a `build`. I don't want the user to wait until the whole command output is available i.e. the command has finished, but progressively render the output (e.g. render some lines of the output each second or something similar). I am using `Spring/Spring MVC` but if somebody has to propose a solution without it that's fine.

My first though was to spawn in a separate `thread` the command line `job` and correlate the user's `sessionid` with the `threadid` that is executing the command but I don't actually know how it would be best to proceed from this point on, or even if this is a proper solution.

Has anybody done something similar? Is there a `standard` way to achieve such a feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would design something like this.

```
Upon Click
    Generate ID
    Start Thread for executing the Task

Thread
    Create an entry for this ID in a global Map
    Start Process
    Watch OutputStream from the Process forked for executing the build
    Buffer to accumulate X lines
    Re-Set the X lines of String as Value for that ID in Map

Auto-Refresh with ID from your Page
    Check for the String and Update Page
```

Maybe, you can have more details like whether the Job is in progress, failed or completed too in the Map for easy management.

Comment: thanx for your answer. I just finished the implementation and I believe it is going on fine. I also followed your suggestion and created a bean containing various execution info and assigned that as the value type of the global map.